# Jest cannot parse error with Jest + Enzyme testing in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, enzyme

I am facing issue with jest testing.. 
Basically I have made configuration with following steps:

script in package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/jest-script-preprocessor",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.*[.](jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|less|LESS|css|CSS)$": "EmptyModule"
    },
    "preprocessorIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
      "<rootDir>/EmptyModule.js"
    ]
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.x | ^7.0.0-0"
  }
```

And in jest-script-preprocessor.js

```
import babelJest from 'babel-jest'
    module.exports = {
      process: (src, filename) => {
        return babelJest.process(src, filename)
          .replace(/^require.*\.less.*;$/gm, '')
      }
    }
```

Let me know valuable way to get it resolve.

[image]

Comment: Can you include the contents of the test file that is throwing the error? Also, could you include the error as text in your question instead of an image, it will make it easier for people to find the answer in the future

Comment: Actually I am using webpack here.. after adding jest & enzyme in project setup.. It gives me the error. I think problem with babel and jest configuration.